# Where did Eddie Van Halen comment that everything resets in the music industry about every 10 years?

Tags: reference-request, van-halen

I remember reading a comment from Eddie Van Halen in a music or guitar magazine a few decades ago, about how every 10 years or so there's a reset in the music industry, and a new style or approach to music makes it easy for beginners to get started, no longer competing with seasoned experts (who are already devoted to an older approach).

I've [googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=eddie%20van%20halen%20every%2010%20years%20in%20music%20industry) (and DuckDuckGo'ed) to no avail.

Does anyone else remember this comment?  Does anyone remember where he said this?